# graphics with baposter

Tags: graphics, color, baposter

I'm trying to include some plots into my poster. I would like the plot background to have the same color as my poster-boxes and the panel background to be white. Hence I create plot in R, but the colors are slightly different (in latex cmyk 0, 0, 0.3, 0; in R rgb 255, 255, 179).

[image]

Moreover there is a border around the plot which annoys me.

Is there any easy way how to fix it or how to create transparent figures to avoid this problem?

My code

```
\documentclass[landscape, a0paper, fontscale=0.285]{baposter}

\definecolor{silver}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.3}
\definecolor{yellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.9,0.0}
\definecolor{reddishyellow}{cmyk}{0,0.22,1.0,0.0}
\definecolor{black}{cmyk}{0,0,0.0,1.0}
\definecolor{darkYellow}{cmyk}{0,0,1.0,0.5}
\definecolor{darkSilver}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.1}

\definecolor{lightyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.3,0.0}
\definecolor{lighteryellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0.0}
\definecolor{lighteryellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0.0}
\definecolor{lightestyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.05,0.0}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{
headerborder=closed, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=0.5em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=lighteryellow, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=lightestyellow, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=reddishyellow, % Border color
headerColorOne=yellow, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=reddishyellow, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=black, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=lightyellow, % Background color of the content boxes
boxColorTwo=lighteryellow,
textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.2\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=rectangle, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=1.5pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
}
{}
{Joe's research}
{Joe Doe \\ 
University of Nowhere\\}
{}

\headerbox{Introduction}{name=introduction,column=0,row=0}{
\lipsum[2]

\includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{plotA.png}

\vspace{0.3em} % When there are two boxes, some whitespace may need to be added if the one on the right has more content
}


\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would use a graphics editor to convert white to transparent (you need to add a transpaency layer/alpha channel first).

Comment: The last part of your question is an R question, not a LaTeX question, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550435/issue-saving-r-plot-with-transparent-background